# Is the comic book in the Take On Me music video real?

Tags: story-identification, comics, music, rock-music, take-on-me

*Take On Me* may very well have the greatest music video of all time.

This music video prominently features a comic book.

[image: Take on me comic]

Was this comic book a real, previously existing one? If not, is its creator know?

Update: For those voting to close, the video is definitely fantasy as it features a comic book character coming to life and bringing a woman into his world. The comic itself is also arguably science fiction.

Comment: And perhaps [the second best video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HE9OQ4FnkQ)...

Comment: Inspired by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) if the allegations are true. I believe it.

Comment: I recommend asking this on [musicfans.se]. While the video itself may employ the common fantasy trope of getting [sucked into fiction](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SuckedIntoFiction) through a [portal book](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PortalBook) and thus being somewhat on topic, extending that to the comic book used seems a bit of a stretch. Of course, it _would_ be fully on topic on the (shameless plug) _Area 51_ proposal **[Comics, Cartoons & Animation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94426/comics-cartoons-animation?referrer=WpIP95MxAOelvQRFh5DO2w2)**.

Comment: This seems pretty on topic to me.

Comment: Norway? The song? The country? Are we expecting more [tag:norway] questions? (By the way, I would vote to reopen if I could.)

Comment: A-ha is a Norwegian band. There are also some Norway related [questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=norway) on the site.

Comment: Ah, so there are. Got it. And....... that untagging was not my doing, clearly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[It was an original work](http://www.bbc.com/news/entertainment-arts-11485702), albeit one based on a comic book that Steve Barron had read as a child, and animated by Mike Patterson.

> A concept was devised by Steve Barron, based on a comic book he read as a young child featuring "guys racing against each other on motorbikes and sidecars".
>
> A girl reading a comic book in a greasy spoon cafe - played by Bunty Bailey of dance troupe Hot Gossip - is attracted to a sketched version of Harket before she finds herself sucked into the animated world.
>
> The pair are pursued by violent motorcyclists before the singer breaks out of the animation and the pair are finally reunited in the real world.
>
> The band and actors were shot on film before the tapes were handed to Mike Patterson who, over 16 weeks, sketched some 3,000 drawings over individual frames.
>
> "I knew that it was going to look good but I had no idea it was going to be in heavy rotation on MTV for a year," says Patterson, who worked on the video with wife Candace Reckinger.

As seen in the text above, the majority of the film consisted of filmed footage which was then drawn over. You can see [an image of the set here](http://www.theguardian.com/culture/2015/sep/15/a-ha-how-we-made-take-on-me):

[image]

Comment: Which comic book was it inspired by?

Comment: Wait, motorcyclists? I thought they were evil Plumbers.

Comment: @Valorum: I've sent an email to the contact points on his website. Hopefully, someone will respond.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots did they?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage: No. :(